# DL stacking, do I miss some CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am using recursive DL elements as follows:

```
<dl>
  <dt>1</dt>
  <dl>
      <dt>1.1</dt>
      <dl>
         <dt>1.1.1</dt>
      </dl>
  </dl>
</dl>
```

In Firefox this is rendered as follows:

```
1
   1.1
       1.1.1
```

But on Chrome and Internet Explorer I only get:

```
1

1.1

1.1.1
```

How can I write code that renders similarly on Firefox
and Chrome/Internet Explorer. Some special styling of
DL with CSS? I prefer the Firefox rendering.

P.S.: Normally dl has at least one dd or dt. The definition 
is `<!ELEMENT dl (dt|dd)+>`. So I guess it is allowed to 
only have a dt and no dd. But what is unorthodox, is to 
have a dl inside a dl.

Comment: I'm guessing that they have some default padding or margin, try to set those to 0

Comment: You can't nest DL elements like that. That's invalid. A DL can only have DT and DD children. (I'm not sure that having a DL as a DD of another DL makes sense either - if a single term has multiple descriptions you would represent that as one DT followed by as many DDs as necessary, and, well, that's all I can think of.)

Comment: normally `dl` should have `dd` (which stands for *data description*).

Comment: Yes `<dd></dd>` solves the problem without CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css:

```
dl:not(:first-child) {
    /* "dl dl" and "dl ~ dl" are also possible solutions.
       They will work on old browsers, too */
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

This code will set margin on all `dl` tags except the first one.

[Demo working on both Chrome and Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/qv33V/)

Comment: Could indicate a possible solution. But better would be something along not(nesting_level=0). Since your solutions breaks, if the text contains another <dl></dl> root before this <dl></dl> root. Maybe something along dl dl { margin-left: ... }.

Comment: Yes, http://jsfiddle.net/v3tvV/ does the job. Still a difference in Chrome and Internet Explorer with the top and bottom margin/padding. But otherwise fine now.

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot for `dl dl`, I also think it is a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<dd></dd>` pairs around the inner `<dl></dl>` 
does also the job without CSS:

```
<dl>
    <dt>1</dt>
    <dd><dl>
        <dt>1.1</dt>
        <dd><dl>
            <dt>1.1.1</dt>
        </dl></dd>
     </dl></dd>
</dl>
```

Is rendered as follows in all 3 browsers:

```
1
   1.1
       1.1.1
```

See also http://jsfiddle.net/C98NX/1/ .

Bye

Comment: Maybe firefox autocompletes the inner `<dl></dl>` with a `<dd></dd>` pair.